# Patagames.Pdf assembly error in pdfium and Navisworks API using WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, pdfium, autodesk-navisworks

Working on an initial plugin for Autodesk Navisworks using WPF and I am trying to load a PDF file to that viewer window. I use PDFium package, installed it as instructed in [patagames website](https://pdfium.patagames.com/help/html/Welcome-to-the-Pdfium-NET-SDK.htm) with NuGet in VS2022.

This is how my control looks like:

```cs
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PdfCommon.Initialize();
    }
}
```

And this is how my plugin file looks like:

```cs
namespace My_Plugin
{
    // assign Plugin Name, devID, Tooltip
    [Plugin("MyPlugin", "ADSK", ToolTip = "MyPlugin", DisplayName = "MyPlugin")]
    [DockPanePlugin(350, 500, FixedSize = false)]
    public class MyPlugin : DockPanePlugin
    {
        public override Control CreateControlPane()
        {
            // WindowForm control to host WPF elem
            ElementHost elemHost = new ElementHost
            {
                //assign wpfcontrol
                AutoSize = true,
                Child = new MyControl()
            };
            //create control
            elemHost.CreateControl();

            return elemHost;
        }

        public override void DestroyControlPane(Control pane)
        {
            pane.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Running the project yields this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Patagames.Pdf, Version=11.76.43.48,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=60fd6cf9b15941cf' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong?